# Why is bachelors' unknotting called as such and who discovered it?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, topology

Bachelors' unknotting is a way to show that all tame knots are isotopic to the unknot, by tightening a knot to a point. Why is it called 'bachelors' unknotting'?

Comment: Note that it is "bachelors' unknotting". The earliest instance I have been able to locate at this time, which provides no explanation of the name, is: Peter R. Cromwell, *Knots and Links*, Cambridge University Press 2004, p. 4: " *Because mathematical thread has no thickness, we can reduce a mathematical know until it becomes a point and disappears. This continuous transformation, known as bachelors' unknotting, is sketched in Figure 1.4* "

Comment: Given that 2004 does not qualify as history in my thinking, I was going to suggest contacting Dr. Cromwell by email, but found that his [staff web page](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/mathematical-sciences/staff/peter-cromwell/) at the University of Liverpool is empty.

Comment: @njuffa I actually learnt about this term from Cromwell's book. I'll see if I find any older source. I initially thought the term might be related to some western cultural norm or custom regarding weddings. Apologies for replying late.

Comment: Possible an instance of British humor? People who get married are said to "tie the knot". If one does that in reverse (unknotting), the groom will then turn back into a bachelor. Just a wild hypothesis.

Comment: @njuffa I found a reference from 2001, earlier than Cromwell: https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/~su14/papers/KNOT2002.pdf. It reads "The one manoeuvre which must be excluded is the analogue of the bachelor’s technique for ignoring knots on a piece of cotton – pull it so tight that you can hardly see it! Using this technique on a curve with no physical thickness would get rid of any knot." on pages 3--4.

Comment: Interesting! Now you can write an answer to the question yourself, which is explicitly permitted by Stack Exchange rules. I admit that I do not know what "knots on a piece of cotton" is supposed to mean. Presumably they mean "cotton string"?

Comment: @njuffa I would have surely written an answer if I had understood the context for 'bachelor's technique'! Why are bachelors in Britain (Morton is British) interested in knots or tangled pieces of cotton on a string?

Comment: I think I did this with cotton shoelaces once as a young man. A knot had formed in the string, and it was too tight to easily undo. Prevented the shoelaces from passing through the eyelets on the shoe. By pulling on the string really hard, I shrank the knot to a minimal size where the shoelaces would fit through the eyelets of the shoe again. The reason this works is that cotton shoelaces are somewhat "fluffy", so a *very* tight knot could have smaller diameter than the string. Anyhow, I am *guessing* that this is the kind of scenario referred to by "knots on a piece of cotton".